# react-native-udp Sochets.createSocket undefined object

Tags: android, react-native

I wanted to included UDP function in my react native app. To do so I used this library:

```
https://github.com/tradle/react-native-udp
```

Usage:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    socket.bind(12345, '0.0.0.0', function(){
        console.log('bound');
    });

  }
```

I followed the instructions to install and link it. But I receive this error anyways:

```
[09:44:01] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Sockets.createSocket')

This error is located at:
    in HomeScreen (at App.js:23)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in App (at registerRootComponent.js:17)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:16)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
- node_modules\react-native-udp\UdpSocket.js:61:10 in UdpSocket
- node_modules\react-native-udp\UdpSockets.js:11:23 in createSocket
* screens\HomeScreen.js:24:38 in componentDidMount
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12144:10 in commitLifeCycles
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13496:8 in commitAllLifeCycles
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:92:15 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:306:36 in invokeGuardedCallback
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13702:8 in commitRoot
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15269:13 in completeRoot
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15197:21 in performWorkOnRoot
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15090:24 in performWork
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15047:14 in performSyncWork
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14925:19 in requestWork
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14711:16 in scheduleWork
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7700:17 in enqueueSetState
- node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:364:31 in setState
* App.js:53:18 in _handleFinishLoading
```

The versions I am using are:

```
"@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^31.0.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-udp": "^2.3.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2"
```

Can someone please confirm or deny the library working properly?

Comment: Have you linked library ?

Comment: yes I ran react-native link and also to be sure react-native link react-native-udp. Is there a way to verify the successfull link? CMD does not output anything

Comment: @dralexnumber I put a bit of debugging work into it and it seems that NativeModules.UdpSockets is undefined